# Mainline DHT unspecified entry in bencoded dictionary

Tags: bittorrent, dht

I have found an entry in a bencoded dictionary in DHT traffic, generated by BitTorrent, which I do not understand, nor can find anything about in the DHT specification at http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html.

Example of packet query and response with wireshark:

```
query = {"a":{"id":".=...4...R..%..s~..;"}, "q":"ping", "t":"..oo", "v":"UThK", "y":"q"}
response = {"r":{"id":"..=..x......o....w/%"}, "t":"..oo", "v":"UT..", "y":"r"}
```

full hex dump can be found here: http://pastebin.com/SMB4f8LR.

The entry in this example is the `"v":"UThK"` in the query and `"v":"UT.."` in the response.
What is its purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `v` field is optional and indicates which client and version is running the DHT node.

The ones that start with "UT" is uTorrent, followed by one byte indicating the major version and another byte for minor version.

Other possible values are:

- "Az" - Azureus (or Vuze)
- "LT" - libtorrent (rasterbar)
- "MP" - MooPolice
- "GR" - GetRight
- "MO" - Monotorrent

Comment: Thanks a lot! Where did you learn this? Are there more details which are not covered in http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html ?

Comment: I implemented it in libtorrent and work on uTorrent. http://libtorrent.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/libtorrent/trunk/src/kademlia/dht_tracker.cpp?revision=6490&view=markup (look for ::send_packet)

Comment: Where did you find out that you should implement it like that to begin with?

Comment: I talked to the guy who wrote uTorrent (which I believe was the first to introduce the version tag)