# what is the structure of bencode reply to get_peers dht request?

Tags: protocols, bittorrent, dht

I am doing packet analysis for dht traffic. I am able to match dht get_peers request to its corresponding response through sniffing packets from my program.

When I decode (bendecode), I am getting following nodes.

```
dict {<br />
    ip => str = xxxxxxxx (len = 6)
    r => dict {
        id => str = O\xb4{|\xc8\x08\xcd!\xaf\x14\xaa\xcb0U\xd7\xb0w\xday\xbe (len = 20)
        nodes => str = tQ\xbd\xa2t\xe3\xfe>\x1a~*-d\x0a\x84\xee\x17\x13\x7f\x81\xad\xc0\xbb\x9c\x1a\xe2uA\x87FL\x0fv,\x12m@u@K\x08\xb7\xeb8;\xc6ST\x10\xd7\x1a\xe9v9w\xaf\xa6@-M\x94YQ\xee\x8f\xe3t\xbd\xb2\xf6\xcb\xc5v\xd3-P\x1a\xe1w\x95\xbd\xc2\xeba\xeb\x9e\x0b\xba\x82\xcb\xa9\x81\x18\xaf\x81\x89\xa1\x81\xd4/\xefG\xc8\xd5p\x84\xb7\x8fD\xff\xf2\x05\xe3,`\xd8A\x03C\xba\x9a\x96C\xdcp\xd2\x8f)\xee\xd1q_\xebH\xe4C4n&\xd2\xe1\xa40\xc6w.\xf5\xf0\xa3\xefB\x1f'\x02\x1a\xe9r\xfc\xcb`\xb3\x17\x10\xd8{\x84\x1eC\xb0\x1f-\xd5\x9b\x1c\xe8\xf6X\xfa(\x87\x1a\xe1sp\x87\xc9\xccS\xbfg\xd6\xbf\x14\xd6~-\xdc\x8ef\x83\xef\xb2^4\xc3W\xd2h (len = 208)
        token => str = \xc6l\x8c\xa4n\xe6H\xa6\x9ae!\x1f\xe9J\x06\x1675\xe5\xad (len = 20)
    }
    t => str = bA (len = 2)
    v => str = UT\xa6P (len = 4)
    y => str = r (len = 1)
}
```

What does t, v mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [bittorrent DHT specification](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html) mentions `t`

> Every message has a key "t" with a string value representing a transaction ID.

`v` is not ocumented, but already covered [by this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9343828/1362755)